# Retrieving date time value upto a millisecond using the DATE() function

Tags: php

By using the function Date(ymdHis) i am able to retrieve the value of the current date and time until seconds.

I wanted to find out what do we need to do so that we retrieve even until a milli second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`microtime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) returns the current time with microseconds. You will have to parse them by hand, though, `date()` can deal only with second-based timestamps.

Check out [this User Contributed Note](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#97441) for an example on how to deal with it.